# Probability of choosing $n$ different numbers over a sample of $n$ numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, random

Suppose I have the set of numbers $[{1,2,3...,10}]$

I (think) I know that if I choose a number randomly, the probability of choosing the $10$ different numbers of the set in $10$ tries is $\frac{10!}{10^{10}}$. This is because on the first try I dont care what number comes out, so the probability of not repeating is $\frac{10}{10}$, but on the second try I dont want to get the first number that I got, so the probability of not repeating is $\frac{9}{10}$ and so on.

My question is, what is the probability of randomly choosing all the numbers of a set that contains $n$ numbers over $X$ tries?

Comment: So when $n=3$ and $X=20$, you are asking for the probability that after $20$ random choices, that you have chosen all of the numbers in $\{2,3,5\}$, for example?

Comment: Yes, exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685679) a version for $n=5$, except it's needed estimated value of $X$, not probability?

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly understood the question of Mike? I would assume that by $n$ you mean the cardinality of the whole set, from which you choose the numbers, not that of its subset.

Comment: @user It seems like a natural enough question to ask, "When a fair dice with $10$ sides is rolled $20$ times, what is the probability that a particular set of $3$ numbers (say, $\{8,9,10\}$) all appeared in one of the rolls?"

Comment: @MikeEarnest It seems even more natural to ask: "When a fair die with $n $ sides is rolled $X $ times, what is the probability that any side appeared at least once?" I know that your answer is much more general and  includes this particular case as well but this can be misunderstand by OP. Especially because you left the number $10$ in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This probability can be computed using the principle of inclusion exclusion to be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\left(\frac{10-k}{10}\right)^X
$$
It helps to understand this by looking at examples for small $n$.

- When $n=1$, the probability is $1-(9/10)^X$. That is, the probability that you do get the one element you want is one minus the probability that you miss it $X$ times in a row.
- When $n=2$, it is $1-2(9/10)^X+(8/10)^X$. There are two numbers $a$ and $b$ in our set. The probability we get both of them seems like it could be calculated by taking $1$, and subtracting the probability that $a$ is not obtained, $(9/10)^X$, and subtracting the probbaility $b$ is not obtained, $(9/10)^X$. However, outomces where *both* $a$ and $b$ are missed have been doubly subtracted, so these must be added back in. This accounts for the $(8/10)^X$ term.

Comment: Note that my initial answer was very wrong, but it is now fixed!

Comment: Is $n=10$ here?

Comment: I think so. If not, the probability of getting the numbers $1, 2$ over the set $\{1,2\}$ in 2 tries would be $0.02$, when it should be $\frac{1}{2}$. Instead, if you replace those 10's by $n$, the final sum would be $1 - 2(\frac{1}{2})^2 + 0^2$ which is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$